# JS: Object restructuring (using map) - add regex to some value

Tags: javascript

I can execute this code only that it works on the array:

```
bills.map((bill) => ({
        ...bill,
        amountMoney: bill.amountMoney.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' '),
        accountBillNumber: bill.accountBillNumber
          .replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1 ')
          .trim(),
      }));
```

Unfortunately, but this time, my `bills` is an object with the same structure.

```
const bills = { amountMoney: 0.22, accountBillNumber: 1234567890 }
```

I would like to restructure it and add regex formatting to the value, just like I do for `bills` `array`.

Comment: I assume the values you provided are actually strings (not `Number`s) since that seems to be what your formatting function expects.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is just about how to handle a single object instead of an array? If so, you can just extract out your formatting function:

```
const formatSingleBill = (bill) => ({
  ...bill,
  amountMoney: bill.amountMoney.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' '),
  accountBillNumber: bill.accountBillNumber
    .replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1 ')
    .trim(),
});

// If you have an array
bills.map(formatSingleBill);

// If you have a single object
const bills = { amountMoney: '0.22', accountBillNumber: '1234567890' }
const reformatted = formatSingleBill(bills);
```